# Can i set dynamically the name of a shortcut while deploying with the VS Setup Deployment Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment, prebuild

i would like to publish my application with a name (and desktop shortcut) based on a config file.

So can i dynamically set the name of a shortcut while deploying with the VS Setup Deployment Project?

**PS.** I mean, we have also the pre-build and the post-build option. Aren't we?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Windows Installer doesn't support this. A shortcut name cannot be changed dynamically during install:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371847(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368590(VS.85).aspx

A solution is to create the shortcut through a custom action. For example a custom EXE written by you which creates the shortcut through Windows API.